# Not able to perform drag and drop in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhRDz.png) I am trying with below code to **drag and drop** from source to target but its not finding my source element through different locators.

I Have a `button` and while clicking it leads to the new `popup` window , I can switch to the new window but its  not finding my elements there to perform **drag and drop**.

**My Code:**

```
//While clicking on this button , It opens a new window  
Managedealassets.click();
//Switching my control to the new window
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
WebElement From = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[21]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/ul/li/ul/li/div/span"));
WebElement To = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[21]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/ul/li/div/span"));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
Action dragAndDrop = builder.clickAndHold(From)
.moveToElement(To)
.release(To)
.build();
dragAndDrop.perform();
}
}
```

**HTML Code**:

I have attached a screen for `HTML` Code

[image: screen]
[image: screen]

Comment: please add the html code as text, not as screenshot. this makes it difficult to read and to help. so please remove the html screenshot and add the important parts as text in here. please also intend by four spaces. thanks

Comment: What is the html of the element you are trying to 'drag' and what is the html of the element you are trying to 'drop to'. Note, those XPaths you've used will either a) be very unreliable b) wont work

Comment: It worked for me now , Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Managedealassets.click(); `/Switching my control to the new window
  driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
WebElement From = driver.findElement(By.id("SelectedAssets"));
List<WebElement> DealAssignedAssets = From.findElements(By.tagName("span"));







for (WebElement element : DealAssignedAssets)  {
if (element.getText().equals("Various vehicles"));
{

WebElement To = driver.findElement(By.id("UnAssignedApplicationAssets"));


List<WebElement> UnAssignedApplicationAssets = To.findElements(By.tagName("span"));


for (WebElement element11 : UnAssignedApplicationAssets )  {

    if (element.getText().equals("Various LDV's"));




    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);


    Action dragAndDrop = builder.clickAndHold(element)

            .moveToElement(element11).release().build();

            dragAndDrop.perform();




}`
```